# JavaScript Variable returning null when entering for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some code that should output the accumulation of a string eg.

`abc` would = `A Bb Ccc`

But when I test it the input and output get assigned `abc` and "" respectively, but once the for loop happens the code just stops and returns null.

Anyone can explain why? I tried SubString instead of charAt to no avail.

```js
function accum(s) {

  //storage
  var input = s;
  var output = "";

  // capitalize first letter
  for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    output = input.charAt(i);
    output.toUpper();

    for (var j = i; j < i; j++) {
      output += output.toLower();
    };

    return output;
  };

}
console.log(accum("abc"));
```

Comment: Did you mean `i < s.length`? Did you mean `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: yes.. awesome thanks. Getting my head around switching syntax, the tool I'm using didn't even bring these up as errors

Comment: Are you using notepad? :D

Comment: might as well be!, no I run it through http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit, which is really good. But doesn't advise of any syntax errors etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first for loop should have the condition i < s.length, as opposed to i < s.